Why when referring to the Ark does the torah mention the "cover" כפורת of the ark and not the ark itself?
In the opening of Parashat Acharei-Mot, God cautions Aaron against entering the Holy of Holies and approaching the covering of the Ark, citing the divine cloud that will manifest above it.
What is the significance of the Ark's covering, and why does the Torah specifically reference it rather than the Ark itself?

This link seems to talk about the significance of the Kapores, but my Hebrew is not great: https://www.etzion.org.il/he/tanakh/studies-tanakh/core-studies-tanakh/ark-kaporet-and-keruvim-v

https://www.chabad.org/therebbe/article_cdo/aid/3316067/jewish/27-Adar-II.htm

@shmosel sounds like it could be an answer to the question, but I'm just not catching the main idea, if someone could put it together succinctly/simply that would be great

Yes, there's a lot packed in there. The basic theme is common in chassidus; here is nice overview. Basically, the mistake of Nadav and Avihu was losing themselves in spiritual ecstasy instead of integrating G-dliness into their reality. In the above explanation, the cover of the Ark represents the need to curb our whims and desires, even in pursuit of spirituality, to fulfill what G-d wants of us in the real world, which ultimately is the only way of reaching the highest spiritual levels.

First I will briefly summarize the point brought by the article at etzion.org.il which in itself is based on the words of Rabbi Shlomo Fisher zt"l in his ספר בית ישי סימן מז:ב within the article המח והלב (see there in Hebrew starting at page 367). R, Fisher states that there are two different vantage points regarding the interaction between the ארון and כפרת.

The ארון is the main component and the כפרת accompanies and serves it OR
The כפרת is the main component and the ארון accompanies and serves it

It could be that the second vantage point is being stressed at the beginning of פרשת אחרי מות.
Not mentioned in the article but very connected and interesting to note is that the only time the כפרת is mentioned in Tanach outside of the Chumash is when David is described as giving Shlomo the blueprints for the future mikdash:

(דברי הימים א כח:יא) וַיִּתֵּן דָּוִיד לִשְׁלֹמֹה בְנוֹ אֶת תַּבְנִית הָאוּלָם וְאֶת בָּתָּיו וְגַנְזַכָּיו וַעֲלִיֹּתָיו וַחֲדָרָיו הַפְּנִימִים וּבֵית הַכַּפֹּרֶת

Here, the commentaries interpret בֵ֥ית הַכַּפֹּֽרֶת as קדש הקדשים (and it's strikingly not mentioned as a בית הארון or בית העדות).
I will also take a shot at venturing a different idea that specifically addresses your dilemma and even takes into account the notion that the ארון and לוחות are the primary components.
This focuses on the need for a form of covering or protection for those who are fit to encounter G-d's presence so that it won't be a direct exposure to גילוי שכינה which no mortal can survive. Once the לוחות were placed in the ארון there was always a sense of danger for someone coming in direct contact.
Indeed there are extra outer layers of cover for the לוחות in addition to the כפרת such as the כרובים and the פרכת - the latter mainly serving as a wall or partition to the קדש הקדשים but even serving as an actual cover and wrapping for the ארון while the משכן would travel.
At the beginning of אחרי מות it can be said that the כפרת cover is a close as one can get to the core when the kohen approaches it and sprinkles the blood of the sacrifices upon the כפרת. So here the dual meaning of a cover and a tool for atonement (כפרה) are implied.
When the כפרת is first introduced in פרשת תרומה and we are told that this would be the focal point where G-d would communicate with Moshe during the travels in the desert - perhaps this also hints to the idea that this is as close as Moshe gets and no closer.
In אחרי מות, we are also told the key line בענן אראה על הכפרת - that G-d will appear upon the כפרת in a cloud - also a notion of covering (and possibly referring to the cloud-smoke of the קטורת).  While this notion appears in a number of places in Tanach, there is an added element here which will connect this section to a critical point in פרשת כי תשא. We learn at the end of this section that this service is to be performed every year on Yom Kippur. Our sages tell us that the day Moshe received the 2nd set of לוחות (and on which G-d revealed the 13 attributes of mercy) coincided with Yom Kippur - each parsha referring to a time of a dramatic atonement and referring to an encounter with an important element of the ארון structure (the כפרת and לוחות). See שמות לג:יב - לד:ט but specifically the words:

ושכתי כפי עליך - indicating a covering - note the similarity of the word כפי to כפרת

and then

וירד ה' בענן ויתיצב עמו שם - noting the appearance of G-d in a cloud (interesting that this בענן and the aforementioned one are the only times this word occurs in Tanach with the trop of זקף-קטן)

Possibly offering support for the idea that these two parshios inform each other in their notion of the need for a shrouded encounter with G-d are the following:

Yalkut Shimoni on מלכים א פרק ח (סימן קפט) discusses each of the critical two wordings above in close proximity
The Ibn Ezra on שמות לג:כב interprets ושכתי כפי as "like a cloud covers the light of the sun" (based on (איוב לו:לב) על כפים כסה אור)
The Abarbanel there in כי תשא agrees with the interpretation of the Ibn Ezra and also states:


ועוד יסוכך עליו בענן הכבוד שמשם היה יוצא הדבור למשה בהיותו באהל ועל זה אמר ושכתי כפי עליך עד עברי רוצה לומר שילוה אליו העזר האלקי מענן כבודו לעזרו בהשגת הדרכים והמדות ההמה כי מלת כף יאמר על ענן כמו (איוב ל״ו:ל״ב) על כפים כסה אור

